# Facing issues while converting django-cms into Headless CMS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, content-management-system, django-cms

My company is using `django-cms` as the CMS. However, recently we need to convert it into headless CMS so that we can have our custom view layer to improve speed and performance.

I got a very few articles online but none of them helped

**Here is what I have understood till now:**

The core team for `django-cms` had started development for `headless` mode but it was not completed or is not supported now (visit article: https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2017/03/14/headless-django-cms/ for more details).

I found 2 plugins such:

- [`djangocms-rest-api`](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-rest-api) which was archived and it recommends using `djangocms-spa`
- [`djangocms-spa`](https://github.com/dreipol/djangocms-spa) which looks like is a good choice but I am not finding any good documentation for the usage. Also, the git repository looks like is not frequently updated.
- There is [`django-rest-framework`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which seems can be integrated and used. Tried integrating it but there were a lot of errors.

**Requirement:**

- Any plugin which can be easily integrated without frontend developers having the need to learn django/python in detail code wise (I am mainly looking for this option)
- If django-cms is not the best option then do I have another alternative cms which can easily accommodate this, is secure and performant.

My impression is that `djangocms-spa` and `django-rest-framework` are the only choice (former being better) but they both need someone with python/django background to integrate and make them work properly. Am I right?

Found this article also: https://blog.dreipol.ch/how-we-extended-django-cms-to-create-a-single-page-application-9175c6aad0da which is almost 3 years old

Any examples/repos/articles which can help me to integrate the plugins or give further insights will be highly appreciated.
Let me know if there are any questions which I need to answer.

PS: *The question might not fit exactly as per stackoverflow but I am not aware of any other platforms for the same. Let me know if I can post the same at other place or this can be improved. I am a UI developer with 0 experience with django-cms/django/python*

Comment: I am having the same issue, thats why I am starting looking into wagtail. They have a headless implementation and it seems to be working better